# how to judge declare param is null on using trigger in Oracle10g?

Tags: triggers, oracle10g

I have defined the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  C_INS_TASK_INSERT   
BEFORE INSERT       
ON C_INS_TASK  
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE v_yearPaoIdOld VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN   

  SELECT BSNUM into v_yearPaoIdOld FROM T_INS_BUSINESSINFO bs
  WHERE bs.pbsnum = :new.CBSNUM AND bs.permid = :new.PERMID AND ROWNUM =1;

  IF(v_yearPaoIdOld IS NOT NULL) THEN
    :NEW.BSNUM := v_yearPaoIdOld;
    :NEW.isstart := '1';
    :NEW.isfinish := '6';
    :NEW.starttime := systimestamp; 
  END IF;
END;
```

```
when I execute this code ,I get that error .And then remove the trigger, the next picture is good,so I guess  error in `IF(v_yearPaoIdOld IS NOT NULL) THEN`,but I don't know how to do it.

[image: trigger]

[image: pl/sql]

Comment: The error is ORA-24344 which means there is a compilation error. What is the compilation error?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is the null check? What does `show errors` report after you create the trigger and get that warning? If your client supports that; if not you can query the `user_errors` view to what is actually wrong. I'd guess you have a mistake in a column name.

Comment: when I remove ` IF(v_yearPaoIdOld IS NOT NULL) THEN` and `END IF;`this trigger is happy execute.

Comment: In your second image (why have you posted images instead of text?) you've kept the `if...` and that works. Anyway, with tables created to match the columns you are referencing the trigger compiles OK. Please add the DDL for both tables to the question (as formatted text).

Comment: I don‘t know why, I use navicat,It's wrong. My leader let me gave sql to him ,and he execute the sql ,it's ok,and using plsql developer. how to explain this appearance？ no！！